# Beautiful Header Shapes Using Pseudo:Before Trick, Adding SPACE

Tags: css, pseudo-element, shapes

With a little help, it's almost GORGEOUS: [TheZoo.com/shapes](http://TheZoo.com/Shapes)

Except, there is no space between the header icon and the text, which I want to control. So how do I add margin (or padding) to a css pseudo:before shape, while AVOIDING extra markup, spacer div or other elements, relying purely on the CSS in one class, such as my star1 class?

I tried adding all kinds of padding, margin settings but it distorted the shape. The concise way would be  Words Are Everything

Thanks for the help! Here's a snippet but probably viewing source on the page is better.

```
h2.star2:before  {
                width: 10px;
                height: 20px;
                border-left: 7px solid transparent;
                border-right: 7px solid transparent;
                border-top: 70px solid #c0d3eb;
    /* position: absolute; */
                content: "";
                float: left;

            }

            h1.star1:after, h1.star1:before {
                width: 10px;
                height: 90px; /* This value changes nothing ? */
                border-left: 7px solid transparent;
                border-right: 7px solid transparent;
                border-top: 70px solid #c0d3eb;
                position: absolute;
    content: "";

                }


            div.star3 {
                width: 10px;
                height: 20px;
                border-left: 7px solid transparent;
                border-right: 7px solid transparent;
                border-top: 70px solid #c0d3eb;
    /* position: absolute; */
                float: left;


            }

            div.star3:after {
                width: 40px;
                    padding-right: 40px;
                    content: "hello dolly";
                    visibility:hidden;


            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the pseudo right on the titles and use some padding.

If you use linear backgrounds and background-size it can look a bit nicer (and won't show up at ll on older browsers:

```css
.sideShaped {
  margin:1em auto;
  position:relative;
  padding:0 1em;/* tune this */
  display:table; /* or inline-block or else or nothing, optionnal */
}
.sideShaped:before, .sideShaped:after {
  content:'';
  width:0.8em; /* tune this */
  background:linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 49%, blue 51%) right no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 49%, blue 51%) left no-repeat; /* tune the color */
  background-size:50% 130%; /* tune this too if you wish */
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
:before {
  left:0;
}
:after {
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="sideShaped"> title 1 </h1>
<h2 class="sideShaped"> title 2 </h2>
<h3 class="sideShaped"> title 3 </h3>
<h4 class="sideShaped"> title 4 </h4>
<h5 class="sideShaped"> title 5 </h5>
<h6 class="sideShaped"> title 6 </h6>
```

Comment: This is really impressive! ( I know we're not supposed to say thanks...but in a very hushed tone - thanks!) So the spacing issue was dealt with by the first class .sideShaped with padding. That's all it took for the spacing? But then the  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
:before {
  left:0;
}
:after {
  right:0;
}     /////////////////      I've never seen :before by itself.  What did this add to the code?

Comment: top and bottom to zero sized the element to actual size(height) of its parent. left and right is to put them aside , width is there to size them. it works if parent of pseudo element is in relative position .. have fun :)